# Does Heroku 'redeploy' or 'reruns' applications if they break?

Tags: python, heroku

I’ve created a Python script that all it does is run some logic 1x every 24 hours, modifies a `.txt` file and send out a tweet. However, it seems the script is getting redeployed as it’ll resend the message that’s outside the while loop (which is supposed to be infinite) a few times a day.

I suspect it might be because my script goes into the `Exception`? But I haven’t run into that error at all while testing.

This is what the script looks like:

```
import tweepy

env_path = Path(‘.’) / ‘.env’
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)

SLEEP_TIME = 86400  # 1 day, in seconds

def send_tweet(message):
  tweet(message)

def read_last_tweet_id(file_name):
    file_read = open(file_name, ‘r’)
    last_tweet_id = file_read.read()
    file_read.close()
    return last_tweet_id

def store_last_tweet_id(file_name, last_tweet_id):
    file_write = open(file_name, ‘w’)
    file_write.write(last_tweet_id)
    file_write.close()
    return

def tweet_on_mondays():

    last_tweet_id = read_last_tweet_id(LAST_TWEET_FILE)

    while True:

        if date.today().weekday() == 0:  # It’s Monday

            try:
                new_tweet_id = last_tweet_id + 1
                send_tweet(‘It’s Monday dudes’)
                last_tweet_id = new_tweet_id
                store_last_tweet_id(last_tweet_id)

            except Exception as ex:

                print(‘EXCEPTION >>>’, ex)
        else:
            print(‘not a Monday, not sending tweet out’)

        time.sleep(SLEEP_TIME)

tweet(“I should only run once, as it goes into a while loop afterwards”)
tweet_on_mondays()
```

Also is there a place on Heroku I can verify whether my application crashed and got redeployed?

Answer (score 1):

> all it does is run some logic 1x every 24 hours, modifies a `.txt` file and send out a tweet

The "1x every 24 hours" part of this should not be part of your application.

Rewrite your script to just do the logic, modify the `.txt` file, and send out a tweet. Then deploy as a `worker`, e.g. by creating a `Procfile` like this:

```
worker: python path/to/your/script.py
```

[Scale your worker dynos down to zero](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-dyno-scale) so this doesn't run all the time:

```
heroku ps:scale worker=0
```

And schedule the script to run using [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler):

1. Provision the addon with `heroku addons:create scheduler:standard`
2. Open the scheduler with `heroku addons:open scheduler`
3. Add a task with the right frequency and enter `worker` as the command

You can use a different name for your command if you wish. Just make sure to change both the `Procfile` and the sheduled job to use the same name. Anything other than `web` or `release` is fine.